# Using Google Chrome ttsengine for speech input

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, text-to-speech

I am developing a chrome extension and using tts and ttsengine for speech i/o. But my extension have my chrome to crash without a useful error code (Chrome quits unexpectedly with `Process:         Google Chrome [888]`)

When I call the javascript method `chrome.experimental.speechInput.start(function(){})` chrome crashes.

I tried another extension provided by google which is Speech Recognizer and it works well, also the speech input in google.com works well. Experimental flag has been set.

Is there any additional permission to give or any other procedure to make speech-to-text work?

My manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "my_extension",

"version": "0.1",

"manifest_version": 2,

"description": "my description",

"icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
},

"app": {
    "launch": {
        "local_path": "/twitter/index.html"
    }
},

"offline_enabled": true,

"permissions": [
    "experimental",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "https://api.twitter.com/*",
    "ttsEngine",
    "tts"
],

"tts_engine": {
    "voices": [{
        "lang": "de",
        "event_types": ["end"]
    }]
}
}
```

---

My .js file:

```
function startSpeechInput() {
    chrome.experimental.speechInput.onError.addListener(recognitionFailed);
    chrome.experimental.speechInput.onResult.addListener(recognitionSucceeded);
    chrome.experimental.speechInput.onSoundEnd.addListener(recognitionEnded);

    chrome.experimental.speechInput.isRecording(function (recording) {
        if (!recording) {
            chrome.experimental.speechInput.start({ 'language': 'en-US' }, function(){
                            //TODO
                    }

                    console.log("Voice recognition started!");
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Pressed Record while it is already recording. Do nothing...');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me with your content after some changes.

***Screenshot***

[image: Out put Generated]

**Manifest.json:**

```
{
"name": "my_extension",

"version": "0.1",

"manifest_version": 2,

"description": "my description",

"icons": {
    "16": "icon.jpg",
    "128": "icon.jpg"
},

"app": {
    "launch": {
        "local_path": "index.html"
    }
},


"background":{
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "offline_enabled": true,

"permissions": [
    "experimental",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "https://api.twitter.com/*",
    "ttsEngine",
    "tts"
],

"tts_engine": {
    "voices": [{
        "lang": "de",
        "event_types": ["end"]
    }]
}
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
function recognitionFailed(error) {
  alert("Speech input failed: " + error.code);
}

function recognitionSucceeded(result) {
  alert("Recognized '" + result.hypotheses[0].utterance + "' with confidence " + result.hypotheses[0].confidence);
}
function startSpeechInput() {
    chrome.experimental.speechInput.onError.addListener(recognitionFailed);
    chrome.experimental.speechInput.onResult.addListener(recognitionSucceeded);
    chrome.experimental.speechInput.onSoundEnd.addListener(function (){
        console.log("started");
    });

    chrome.experimental.speechInput.isRecording(function (recording) {
        if (!recording) {
            chrome.experimental.speechInput.start({ 'language': 'en-US' }, function(){

                    console.log("Voice recognition started!");
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Pressed Record while it is already recording. Do nothing...');
        }
    });
}
startSpeechInput();
```

**background.js**

```
function dummy() {

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I don't know what is wrong but it still crashes. Also in my friend's chrome(mine is mac and he has a windows machine) The js code fragment should work on console as well but when I copy paste the index.js file that you modified, it crashes. Is there any other flag that you enable rather than experimental? Or any idea what would be the problem on my chrome?

Comment: which console are you referring to?? How are you testing on console. BTW i am also on Mac.

Comment: uh okay. I mean the javascript console in chrome debugger

Comment: can you try adding latest manifest file and background.js(which i have added now), it wont crash now.

Comment: Yeah I have a non-crashing extension right now finally :) Thanks. I had ignored the background property since it was not clearly said to be included to manifest on ttsengine page but now added that option and it works without a problem. Thanks again!